# How do I change option name?

Tags: 8, forms

I have sort link 'Best' in exposed form. I want after user click this link, link title changes to 'New'

I'm try this, but it don't work:

```
function helper_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form['#id']== 'views-exposed-form-pozdravleniya-taxonomy-term-page-1') {
      $form['sort_by']['#title'] = '';
      $form['sort_by']['#options']['created'] = '';
      if ($form['sort_by']['#value'] == 'count') {
        $form['sort_by']['#options']['count'] = 'New';
      }
    }
}
```

Also I'm try this, it don't work too:

```
function helper_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form['#id']== 'views-exposed-form-pozdravleniya-taxonomy-term-page-1') {
      $form['sort_by']['#title'] = '';
      $form['sort_by']['#options']['created'] = '';
      if ($form_state->getValue('sort_by') == 'count') {
        $form['sort_by']['#options']['count'] = 'New';
      }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot form dump]

Comment: I think maybe you need achive it by javasript instead of form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65888182/13738862

```
function helper_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form['#id']== 'views-exposed-form-pozdravleniya-taxonomy-term-page-1') {
      $form['sort_by']['#title'] = '';
      $form['sort_by']['#options']['created'] = '';
      if ($form_state->getUserInput()['sort_by'] == 'count') {
        $form['sort_by']['#options']['count'] = 'New';
      }
    }
}
```